# How to disable click event on span tag - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html-table

I want to disable based on a condition the click event that 'delete hours' with the 'X' symbol. Thanks in advance.

```
<table navigatable class="<some_class>">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of list; let i=index">
            <td style="width: 95%">{{item}}</td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <span class="<some_class>" (click)="DeleteHour(i)">X</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: "...disable visually the rows of this table." What does that mean?

Comment: @Marc I mean disable with CSS because this is not an input element.

Comment: You just restated the part that's confusing.... and/or augmented the confusion.  "...disable with CSS...".  What does that mean?  What would the end state of that look like?  You've already stated that it's not an input element, so it doesn't observe a `disabled` attribute.  So you need to "invent" the behavior and appearance of your disabled state.  That's the point I'm making, and the point which you haven't clarified.

Comment: I guess you right @Marc. So, I will delete this part of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use an "early return" in DeleteHour(i) to disable the action.

```
const DeleteHour = (i) => {
  if (isDisabled(list[i])) return;
  // ...rest of the function
}
```

For the part "disable visually" I guess it is like changing something visual if it is disabled. If yes you can do something like this :

```
<span class="<some_class>" (click)="DeleteHour(i)">{{ isDisabled(item) ? '' : 'X' }}</span>
```

You can (and maybe should instead) also use a button and use the css pseudo-class `delete-hour:disabled { ...styles }`:

```
<button class="delete-hour" (click)="DeleteHour(i)" [disabled]="isDisabled(item)">X</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @bossno, your answer fits better for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this: (I changed some code in your html as well)

```js
function DeleteHour(e){
e.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  e.parentNode.previousElementSibling.style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<table navigatable class="<some_class>">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of list; let i=index">
            <td style="width: 95%">{{item}}</td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <span class="<some_class>" onclick="DeleteHour(this)">X</span>
              
                          <td style="width: 95%">{{item}}</td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <span class="<some_class>" onclick="DeleteHour(this)">X</span>
              
                          <td style="width: 95%">{{item}}</td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <span class="<some_class>" onclick="DeleteHour(this)">X</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```